Flutter on Xcode 16.0 beta (16A5171c). unsupported option '-G' for target x86_64-apple-ios14.0-simulator'
I recently upgraded my Apple Macbook Pro With M3 to macOS Sequoia.
If i create new empty flutter project it works fine
But if I add Firebase which use gRPC. it give me this error unsupported option '-G' for target x86_64-apple-ios14.0-simulator'
Physical device [Same error]: unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios14.0'
Simulator iOS 18 [Same error]: unsupported option '-G' for target x86_64-apple-ios14.0-simulator'
Simulator iOS 17 [Same error]: unsupported option '-G' for target x86_64-apple-ios14.0-simulator'
When running using Xcode this files has errors
-BoringSSL-GRPC
 |- tls_record.cc
 |- x_spki.c
 |- x_val.c
 |- x_val.c
 |- x_x509.c
 |- x_x509a.c

flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on macOS 15.0 24A5264n darwin-arm64, locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.22.1 on channel stable at
      /Users/salarpro/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision a14f74ff3a (3 weeks ago), 2024-05-22 11:08:21 -0500
    • Engine revision 55eae6864b
    • Dart version 3.4.1
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/salarpro/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16A5171c
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.90.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.90.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • macOS (desktop)                 • macos                 • darwin-arm64   •
      macOS 15.0 24A5264n darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad • darwin         •
      macOS 15.0 24A5264n darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                    • chrome                • web-javascript •
      Google Chrome 125.0.6422.144

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.



It's a first beta. You can expect major breakage.

As stated in @River2202's answer, there is upstream issue with GRPC. There was a flag (-G) that was previously ignored but is now throwing errors.

Fixed here but not delivered yet: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/36904
You could go to iOS project->Pods->BoringSSL-GRPC->Build Phases->Compile Sources, select all files and remove -GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS to walk around it.


How do you remove the flag from all the files at once?

Also you can use Podfile to fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78633109/5862126

@RafaelZasas did you solve this? I tried deleting all of those files but that was not the solution. The below link to the other answer isn't clear on where to place the part of code.

@JovanM. yes- I’ll paste the code in a bit.
